# put sentences into list - python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, tokenize

I understand that nltk can split sentences and print it out using the following code.
but how do i put the sentences into a list instead of outputing onto the screen?

```
import nltk.data
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
import os, sys, re, glob
cwd = './extract_en' #os.getcwd()
for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(cwd, 'fileX.txt')):
    (PATH, FILENAME) = os.path.split(infile)
    read = open(infile)
    for line in read:
        sent_tokenize(line)
```

the sent_tokenize(line) prints it out. how do i put it into a list?

Comment: huh? `sent_tokenize` returns a list of sentences, at least the docs say "Given a text, returns a list of the sentences in that text".

Comment: it prints a list of sentences. but when i try paragraph=sent_tokenize(line) it doesnt work.

Comment: Are you running this in the Python interpreter?

Comment: @2ero because when defining `f = open(infile)` , **f** isn't the content of the file, it's a kind of pointer in the file, an object memorizing the position of the read/write head of the hard disk. To obtain the file's content , we must do `f.read()`

Comment: @eyquem, you're just wrong. `for line in infile:` is _the_ Python idiom for reading lines from files. Although it only gets individual lines from the file, rather than the whole file at once. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @senderle No, I am right, and you're right. I didn't write that `for line in read` isn't pythonic, I say that the name **read** to designate the file's pointer is baaaad: **read** is then no more the function **read()**, it's the pointer

Comment: alright. the nltk documentation is not very clear. @senderle, nltk.tokenize's sent_tokenize(line) does return a list but it also prints out the  list. problem solved. but how to i access the list? para = sent_tokenize(line) then para[0] ?

Comment: @eyquem, ok, I'll restate myself: "To obtain the file's content, we must do f.read()" is confusing, because "must" suggests that it's the only way to do so. In any case, I agree that using "read" as your file pointer name is not a good choice.

Comment: @senderle Oh , I see, subtile remark, senderle, my expression is ambiguous, you're right. I will pay attention to that from now. I will express: `for line in f` is a way to obtain the content of a file, `f.read()` is another, `f.readlines()` is a third one, `line = 'go' while line: line = f.readline()` is one more... and the first is a very pythonic one. I agree. I upvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simplified version that I used to test the code:

```
import nltk.data
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
import sys
infile = open(sys.argv[1])
slist = []
for line in infile:
    slist.append(sent_tokenize(line))
print slist
infile.close()
```

When called like so, it prints the following:

```
me@mine:~/src/ $ python nltkplay.py nltkplay.py 
[['import nltk.data\n'], ['from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize\n'], ['import sys\n'], ['infile = open(sys.argv[1])\n'], ['slist = []\n'], ['for line in infile:\n'], ['    slist.append(sent_tokenize(line))\n'], ['print slist\n'], ['\n']]
```

When doing something like this, a list comprehension is more concise and IMO more pleasant to read:

```
slist = [sent_tokenize(line) for line in infile]
```

To clarify, the above returns a list of lists of sentences, one list of sentences for each line. If you want a flat list of sentences, do this instead, as eyquem suggests:

```
slist = sent_tokenize(infile.read())
```

Comment: i understand now. it's sort of like declaring a list from a function that returns a list but the functions prints out the list if it isn't input into a variable. sorry still pretty C-minded and the interpreter style is pretty different from perl. yep. the list comprehension is more pleasant but more perl/python like than C. it looks like perl though, so i like it. hahaha. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just FYI, the behavior you're describing only happens in the python interpreter, AFAIK. So if you type `>>> sum([1, 2, 3])` in the interpreter, it prints 6, but if you put the line `sum([1, 2, 3])` in `sum.py` and call `python sum.py` from the command line, nothing happens at all.

Comment: is **sent_tokenize()** able or unable to find sentences in a text containing **\r\n** ? If it can't, `for line in infile:` is necessary. If it can do it, `sent_tokenize(f.read())` should work. But I don't know nltk

Comment: @eyquem, yes, good point, I was thinking the same thing. I checked, and yes, `sent_tokenize` tokenizes across newlines, so `sent_tokenize(f.read())` works.

Comment: @senderle That's why you got the points, that's because you had nltk installed and you could do the test. Eh eh :)

Comment: @senderle, ohh.. now i get how interpreter works. i had been dealing with compilers. @eyquem, noted on my bad python syntax, hahaa..

Answer (score 1):

You must not use a keyword name (read) to name an object of your programm.

.

If you want to append in a list, you must have a list:

```
reclist = []
for line in f:
    reclist.append(line)
```

or with a list comprehension

```
reclist = [ line for line in f ]
```

or using the tools of Python

```
reclist = f.readlines()
```

or I didn't understand what you want

EDIT:

Well, considering the Jochen Ritzel 's remark, you want

```
f = open(infile)
reclist = sent_tokenise(f.read())
```

Comment: Actually `read` isn't a keyword in python... not that I advise using it this way.

Comment: i understand that f.readline() reads a line. the nltk function sent_tokenize(afewsentences) prints out the sentences but i need them onto a list. is there another nltk function that does that? if not, how do i put the output into a new string and then manipulate it?

Comment: @senderle Right ! **read** is the name of a built-in function, that's all, you are right.

Comment: @2ero **readline()** with NO **s** reads a line , and **readlines()** WITH an **s** reads the entire file , cut it in lines , and put them in a list.

Comment: @eyquem, sorry i am in asia now so i dozed off while coding. @harvey thanks for helping with the delete